# How to put the array in SESSION and Start Session

Tags: php, arrays, session

My code through which I wanted to start the session is as follows:

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
$run1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where email='$email' AND school_id='$school_id'"); 
$users = array();
while($user_r = mysqli_fetch_array($run1))
{
    $users[] = array("subject_id" => $user_r['subject_id'],"class_id" => $user_r['class_id']);
    $_SESSION['sub_cls']=$users;
}
```

But I'm not able to start the session and it does not return any value.
How should I start the session?

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: *"How should i start session"* --- `session_start();` perhaps?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Yes at the top of page i have start the session

Comment: 1. Have you started session at the top of your PHP script? 2. You're overwriting `$_SESSION['sub_cls']` value in each iteration of `while()` loop.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Yes i hav started the session at the top of page so what should i do next?

Comment: 1. Fix point no. 2 as stated [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189430/how-to-put-the-array-in-session-and-start-session?noredirect=1#comment69578791_41189430). 2. Do `var_dump($_SESSION['sub_cls']);` outside of the `while()` loop and see what you're getting.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
$run1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where email='$email' AND school_id='$school_id'"); 
$users = array();
while($user_r = mysqli_fetch_array($run1))
{
    $users[] = array( "subject_id" => $user_r['subject_id'], "class_id" => $user_r['class_id'] );

}
  // create session, here we stored session in sub_cls variable 
   $_SESSION['sub_cls'] = $users;
```

Read session value in read_session.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['sub_cls']['subject_id'];
    echo $_SESSION['sub_cls']['class_id'];
?>
```

Comment: @Parveenchauhan Thanks Bro It Works thank you so much.